# Nested group results in too many hits on the server

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following query:

```
var articleGroups = from article in _Context.ArticleVersions
                    group article by article.ArticleID into articleGroup
                    select new
                    {
                        ArticleID = articleGroup.Key,
                        ArticleFound = articleGroup.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
                                                   .First()
                    };
```

This query is being executed against a set of CMS tables that stores versioned articles.

I get the correct result, but I noticed when I output the 'execution plan' the SQL query seems to be run once for each article found.

I'm assuming it has to do with the OrderByDescending, but since I'm still learning the ins and outs of Linq I'm not sure how to improve this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var res = from article in _Context.ArticleVersions
          group article by article.ArticleID  into articleGroup
          select articleGroup.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version).First() into articleOut
          select new {ArticleID = articleOut.ArticleID, ArticleFound = articleOut.Version};
```

This groups the articles by ArticleID and stores them in articleGroup. The first Select, selects the first Article from each item in the group after ordering them by version in descending order. The result of this goes into articleOut. The second Select projects the results from articleOut into a new anonymous type.

Comment: can you perhaps explain what you're doing here in each line? 
Your query groups the articles by ArticleID and stores them in articleGroup. The first Select, selects the first Article from each item in the group after ordering them by version in descending order. The result of this goes into articleOut. The second Select projects the results from articleOut into a new anonymous type... About sum it up?